# How to upload multiple SSL certificate for azure web app

Tags: azure, powershell, ssl, azure-web-app-service, azure-cli

I want to add 100+ custom domains on single azure web app, each domain will have it's own SSL certificate (downloaded from cloudflare).

Is there a way to upload 100+ pfx certificate files from azure cli against each custom domain in one go?

Ex: abc.com with it's own ssl certificate
xyz.com with it's own ssl certificate

I will be required to add custom domains & their ssl certificates in bulk.

Currently, I can upload 1 pfx to the app with this command:

```
New-AzWebAppSSLBinding -WebAppName WebApiStaging -Name devops.prod.xyz -ResourceGroupName Staging -CertificateFilePath C:\prod.pfx -CertificatePassword XXXXXX -SslState SniEnabled
```

Please suggest the possible options. Thanks

Comment: Do you know how to upload just 1 pfx with the azure cli? If you do, please post the code, then we can probably help you write some PowerShell to repeat it for the remaining 99 certs :)

Comment: Thanks @MathiasR.Jessen for your prompt response.
I am using below command to upload 1 pfx file with the azure cli.

Comment: New-AzWebAppSSLBinding -WebAppName WebApiStaging -Name devops.prod.xyz -ResourceGroupName Staging  -CertificateFilePath C:\prod.pfx -CertificatePassword XXXXXX -SslState SniEnabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a look at the *variable* parts of the command you're using:

```
New-AzWebAppSSLBinding -WebAppName WebApiStaging -Name devops.prod.xyz -ResourceGroupName Staging -CertificateFilePath C:\prod.pfx -CertificatePassword XXXXXX -SslState SniEnabled
```

Since it's multiple bindings for a single application, the `-WepAppName` and `-ResourceGroupName` will remain the same, and I assume you'll want to enable SNI for all bindings too - which leaves us with:

- `-Name <domain fqdn>`
- `-CertificateFilePath <path to pfx file>`
- `-CertificatePassword <pfx password>`

So you'll need those 3 pieces of information for every single certificate upload.

I'd suggest you put together a spreadsheet with those 3 columns and save it as a CSV file, eg:

```
"Name","CertificateFilePath","CertificatePassword"
"abc.domain.tld","C:\cert1.pfx","s3cr3tp@ssw0rd"
"def.domain.tld","C:\cert2.pfx","s3cr3tp@ssw0rd2"
...
```

Once you have your CSV, it's as simple as calling `Import-Csv` to import the data, and then just repeat the `New-AzWebAppSSLBinding` call for each row:

```
foreach($row in Import-Csv .\path\to\bindings.csv){
    New-AzWebAppSSLBinding -WebAppName WebApiStaging -Name $row.Name -ResourceGroupName Staging -CertificateFilePath $row.CertificateFilePath -CertificatePassword $row.CertificatePassword -SslState SniEnabled
}
```

Comment: I am trying to import the comma separated CSV by using the same command as mentioned by you, but looks like I've missed something, iCan you please help me to fix this issue. Below is the output of that command.

Comment: New-AzWebAppSSLBinding : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Name'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, 
and then try the command again.
At line:2 char:65
+ ... pSSLBinding -WebAppName WebApiStaging -Name $row.Name -Resour ...
+                                                         ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-AzWebAppSSLBinding], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.WebApps.Cmdlets.WebApps.NewAzureWebAppSSLBinding

Comment: @Atif That would indicate that either 1) your CSV doesn't have a `name` column, or 2) at least one row in the CSV file has no value for the `name` column. Do you see the expected data in the console if you just do `Import-Csv .\path\to\file.csv` without anything else?

Comment: Here is the output of the command `Import-Csv .\path\to\file.csv`

That's the expected output

Name,CertificateFilePath,CertificatePassword  
--------------------------------------------  
testing.apexprod.xyz,C:\apexprod.pfx,admin123

Comment: @Atif It looks like it imported `Name,CertificateFilePath,CertificatePassword` as a single column name. Make sure you quote the individual column values correctly in the CSV file

Comment: Yes, my CSV file was not correct, it's working now, Thanks for your help @Mathias. Really appreciate your time & support.

Comment: @Atif Great to hear, you're most welcome! :)